# Access SAP Tables in DB2

Tags: db2

I have a DB2 database, where few of the tablenames are starting with '/'.
eg: /dev/r32

How can I query on the above table?

I have tried with the following approaches:

```
select * from schemaname./dev/r32

select * from schemaname.'/dev/r32'

select * from schemaname."/dev/r32"
```

But I am getting the following error:

> An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
> select * from schemaname."/dev/r32"
>
> [SQL0204] /dev/r32 in schemaname type *FILE not found. [SQL State=42704, DB Errorcode=-204]

`describe schemaname."/dev/r32"` works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't use DB2, but I'm pretty sure IBM there is no error message that says "*didn't work*".

Comment: sorry, here i meant by didn't work was i didn't get any results but error

Comment: updated the question with the error...

Comment: What platform and version of DB2?

Comment: configured db2 details in sql workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table names are changed and issue is resolved.